# Can't access Heapster's InfluxDB port 8083

Tags: docker, kubernetes, influxdb, heapster

I follow [this guide](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/master.md) to deploy my Kubernetes cluster and [this guide](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/influxdb.md) to launch Heapster.

However, when I open Granfa's website UI, it always says "Dashboard init failed: Template variables could not be initialized: undefined". Moreover, I can't access InfluxDB via port 8083. Is there anything I missed?

I've tried several versions of Kubernetes. I can't deploy DNS with some of them, for now I'm using 1.1.4, but I need to create "kube-system" namespace manually. The docker version is 1.7.1.

Edit:
I can curl ports 8083 and 8086 in the influxdb pod. However, I get connection refused if I do that in the node running the container. This is my services status:
[image: svc]

Comment: Did you follow the [troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/influxdb.md#troubleshooting-guide) and verify that the pods are all running?

Comment: Yes, all the pods and services are running. I'm not quite sure how to make the influxDB visible though, I thought it's done in yaml.

Comment: And even if I curl 8086 or 8083 port locally, it says connection refused.

Comment: When you say curl locally, are you curl'ing from *inside* the container or on the node running the container?

Comment: I just found that I can curl 8083 in the pod, but not in the node running the container. I edited the post to show the service status.

Comment: Note that Grafana should be accessing the `/query` endpoint on port 8086. Port 8083 is just for the Web Admin UI.

Comment: When I open Grafana, it just says "Dashboard init failed: Template variables could not be initialized: undefined" and cannot read any data. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with that I can't connect to 8086 outside the container. (I can do that inside the container)

Comment: Port 8083 isn't bound as a host port so it won't be reachable directly from the host on localhost. Can you `10.0.0.3:8083` or `10.0.0.81:8083`?

Comment: No, I got "Network is unreachable" instead.

Comment: can you try go to grafana settings and change database hostname to localhost? And also output of kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system would be heplful